# Proof of History for Ethereum 2.0

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, eth-2.0, scalability

After reading about the Solana-chain, I became convinced that "Proof of History" is a great idea for syncing a decentralized clock and improving scalability.
Be aware that Solana is still a Proof of Stake chain and uses Proof of History as an additional mechanism.

So my question is why I never heard of Proof of History for Ethereum 2.0.
Do the Ethereum devs have specific reasons why they are not implementing Proof of History, or is it just a lack of time and interest?

EDIT: It seems that Solana utilizes Proof of History via the "tower-bft" algorithm: https://medium.com/solana-labs/tower-bft-solanas-high-performance-implementation-of-pbft-464725911e79.

Comment: I have also tried to invent a consensus algorithm based on time. It didn't work for me. You can't trust clocks when you have untrusted nodes so you will be building your blockchain system on a very shaky ground. Time is no doubt a variable that can be used, but it isn't 100% reliable. I don't think Solana chain will pass byzantine fault tolerance test. If they make it and lots of money flows in, thats when the show will start with hackers investing their time in looking for vulnerabilities. Until then it is going to look all beautiful.

Comment: _Messages are time stamped by the sender and the timestamp is signed. Nodes drop messages that are either too old or too new._

keccak() of a timestamp doesn't mean anything if timestamp itself can be forged. Garbage in -> garbage out.

Comment: Even developers of distributed systems with Paxos have lots of warnings about timestamps and constantly repeat you about how unreliable they are. I think Solana is an adventure project with very high risk.

Comment: I believe that Solana is already valuable enough for exploits. Even if you can only steal 500k$, a hacker might still exploit it.

Comment: @Nulik so you mean that the formal security foundations of Solana are shaky, although there has not been a large exploit until now? Perhaps they are lacking formal security proofs?

Comment: nobody is going to seek for vulnerabilities until there is a reward. They will prefer to "invest" the time in hacking Ethereum Classic because there is big trading volume there

Comment: Solana has a 21 Billion USD market cap according to coinmarketcap.com. I know that this market cap is a theoretical number that will quickly collapse in the event of a major exploit, and I also know that market cap does not equal the value of exploitable DeFi-projects. Nevertheless, there should be some incentive to look for Solana-vulnerabilities.

Comment: this market cap is the currency only. but what is the traffic of smart contracts? How many transactions with smart contract execution are there per minute or per second?